# Navigation to previous page from jsf page or from managed bean page

Tags: jsf-2, navigation

I m using JSF2.0. And i want to implement to send back user to previous page when user click on the appropriate button. in addition i don't want to use javascript and jquery. please suggest me any way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use this method in your managed bean:

```
    public void back()
    {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.xhtml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 1.1-1.2: 
You can set the 'config.xml' file something like that:

```
<navigation-case> 
    <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/jsp/previous.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

And in your bean you can call 'returnPrevious' function:

```
public String returnPrevious() {
    return "previous"; 
}
```

Since JSF 2.0 you can do it more easier, look at this link: 
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/